# Loading Depthmap produces wrong values

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to load a depth map generated form blender. 
[image]

OpenCV loads the image and shows one testvalue from the image.

```
cv::Mat depthMap = cv::imread(path, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH);
std::cout << "TestValue: " << depthMap.at<short>(0,0) << std::endl;
```

The output of c++ is the following value:

```
TestValue: 31110
```

Photoshop shows a grey value of 121

I need the values form 0 - 255 or 0 - 1 when loading the depth map so that the testvalue shows 121 or 0.4745. If I normalize the depth map, I get values from 0 - 1 but the highest value in the depthmap is 121 not 255.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what does depthMap.type() give ?

Comment: It says 2 and for the channelnumber it says 1

Comment: so, that is an unsigned short, you should access it as `depthMap.at<unsigned short>(0,0)` (and photoshop silently converts to uchar[0-255])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the data as **short** (signed short int, "at least 16 bits"). Use `unsigned short` instead:

```
std::cout << "TestValue: " << depthMap.at<unsigned short>(0,0) << std::endl;
```

You can try `ushort` as well.

On the other hand, if you want values between 0-255, don't use the CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH flag. Either read the image as 1-channel or convert it to greyscale.

EDITED: as pointed out in the comments, while reading with the CV_LOAD_IMAGE_ANYDEPTH flag, the access should use the correct type: `unsigned short` (int). If you read/convert to greyscale image you can use the `unsigned char` access instead.

Comment: look at the comments, please.

Comment: `cerr << sizeof(uchar) << " " << sizeof(ushort) << endl;` : 1 2